# JQuery issue with with $().load

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load from an external file and it does not do so.

This jQuery file is test.html.
The data file is data.html.

Both in the same folder.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
           $("#btn_01").click(function()
           {
             $("#p1").load("data.html");  

             alert("Hey, jQuery has loaded succesfully!");
           });
        }); 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Buttons -->
    <button id="btn_01">Get Content From Server</button>

    <!-- Paragraphs -->
    <p id="p1">Content from the server displayed below:</p>
</body>
```

data.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p id="my_p1">Here is some content to display.</p>
    <p id="my_p2">Here is some more content to display.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see the request for data.html in your network console returning a 200 with the expected data?

Comment: You can't insert `<p>` inside another `<p>` ... it is invalid. It's possible request is being made but browser is rejecting the insertion

Comment: Tested it on Chrome console gives back: `cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.` Also from the jQuery website: Additional Notes:

Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol. https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Note however [your code works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QScZrsNbQSVInVd2saFG?p=preview), regardless of invalid html. Make sure you are not opening page using `file/open` and are running on server

Comment: @charlietfl I don't think that is the problem. Browsers are lenient for bad HTML. However, I quickly made a folder with the code and it gave me back the cross origin error. Strange, since it is in the same folder.

Comment: @Michelangelo because browser security restricts ajax in `file://` protocol. Will work fine running on localhost server. Look at my demo link that works fine

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, that makes sense then. Maybe OP is just doing it without a localhost.

Comment: @Michelangelo..thanks..I'm doing it without a localhost. From a course I took, i just coded it and double click the test.html file. The course said nothing about a local host.